# Copy multiple files from different folder with same filename to one common folder using windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, copy, command

I have a Folder and some sub folders which contain a file with same file name but different values in it.I have to copy that files to a common folder but i want to keep all the files means i have to rename that files using batch file script in windows

***Input Folder***

> ```
> D:\Data\Logs\Day1\DataLog.txt
> D:\Data\Logs\Day2\DataLog.txt
> D:\Data\Logs\Day3\DataLog.txt
> D:\Data\Logs\Day4\DataLog.txt
> D:\Data\Logs\Day5\DataLog.txt
> D:\Data\Logs\Day6\DataLog.txt
> ```

***Output Folder*** Like

> ```
> D:\Data\Common\Logs\DataLog1.txt
> D:\Data\Common\Logs\DataLog2.txt
> D:\Data\Common\Logs\DataLog3.txt
> D:\Data\Common\Logs\DataLog4.txt
> D:\Data\Common\Logs\DataLog5.txt
> D:\Data\Common\Logs\DataLog6.txt
> ```

i have tried this but its overwriting the existing file

```
pushd D:\Data\Logs
    for /r %%a in (*.*) do (
        COPY  "%%a" "D:\Data\Common\Logs\%%~nxa"
    )
popd
```

Comment: Take a look at this [How to Copy (and increment) Multiple Instances of a File Using Batch File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28697436/how-to-copy-and-increment-multiple-instances-of-a-file-using-batch-file?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: But the source folder have multiple sub folders.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit more of a general approach, but you could try something like this:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "files=d:\data\logs\*.txt"
set "destDir=d:\data\common\logs"

for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir "%files%" /b /s') do (
  for %%d in ("%destDir%\%%~nf*") do (
    set /a count+=1
  )
  xcopy "%%f" "%destDir%\%%~nf!count!%%~xf*"
  set count=
)
```

---

Due to delayed expansion, the last variant of the script is unable to handle files that contain carets (`^`) within their fully qualified path name.

When a command-line contains environment variables that are expanded at execution time (like the `count` variable in this script), the entire command-line seems to be parsed twice. The for-loop variables (`%%f` and variants thereof) will be expanded during the first parse, the `count` variable is expanded during the second parse. Because the for-loop variables are already expanded when the second parse takes place, any singular carets present in the values of the for-loop variables are swallowed by the parser and omitted from the final result.

Here is the revision of the script that should take care of the problem described:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "type=.txt"
set "source=d:\data\logs"
set "dest=d:\data\common\logs"

for /r "%source%" %%f in ("*%type%") do (
  for %%d in ("%dest%\%%~nf*") do (
    set /a count+=1
  )
  set "source=%%f"
  set "dest=%dest%\%%~nf"
  xcopy "!source!" "!dest!!count!%type%*"
  set count=
)
```