# Move thousand files that are each named identically to a single folder and rename them

Tags: cmd, rename, move

I have over thousand folders that are named like this:

```
0a1716b34054ce3ba3bb1bdb2ec71d0d58fe729e  
0a5376e2d5de71dfaf0b07ec6fea3e8c09698e5a  
etc.
```

In these folders are two files each, `__data` and `__info`. They don't have a file extension. I'm trying to move all `__data` files to a single folder and rename them with the following logic:

```
__data(1).unity3d  
__data(2).unity3d  
__data(3).unity3d

etc.
```

I have no idea how to do it. Can someone show me how it's done on Windows 10?

Comment: No, because this is not a tutorial site, but a site for programmers to ask programming-specific questions. Read the [tour] and learn [ask] here! Starting point: [`for`](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html), [`move`](http://ss64.com/nt/move.html).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Copy (and increment) Multiple Instances of a File Using Batch File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28697436/how-to-copy-and-increment-multiple-instances-of-a-file-using-batch-file)

Comment: @LotPings No, it's not a duplicate. Your linked question wants to multiple a single file. I want to move thousand unique files, rename and give them a file extension.

Comment: This is a site for programmers, from programmers it is expected to see a concept and adapt it to the own use case. If you can't do that now you've to continue learning or hire someone who can do the task for you.

Comment: Feedback: the phrase "read my question more carefully" is likely to be regarded by readers as infuriatingly patronising, and is hardly a reason why this is (or is not) a duplicate. If you wish to give a reason as to why this is not a duplicate, go ahead, but _explain your reason_, and do please try to stick to neutral language. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Open parent folder (containing the 1000 folders)
2. In search-field, type "__data"
3. select all __data files
4. press F2
5. enter "__data"
6. after renaming is done, copy all selected
7. create a new folder, paste all renamed elements.

This will a) rename all files, and b) copy them from 1000 folders into one.

Comment: I did that, but it didn't add the file extension.

Comment: I see, it works if you have an extension, but not if there is none.

Comment: Edit: I mass-added the file extension to all files using ren *. *.unity3d. Thanks for the help @KYL3R

Comment: you're welcome, accept my answer. Together with your comment this is the solution.