# Batch File : Move file & If file already exist then keep both with renaming it by numeric sequence (LOOP)

Tags: batch-file

I already found a solution for this but what I need now is to find shortest line of command.
Situation : File "C:\Image.jpg" move to "D:\". If "Image.jpg" exist in "D:\" then rename and move it as "Image01.jpg". This command looping.
Here my batch command line :

```
:start
IF EXIST "D:\Users\00002829\Pictures\Image.jpg" IF EXIST "D:\Users\00002829\Pictures\SFSAPP\VChip_X-Ray\Image03.jpg" (
    move "D:\Users\00002829\Pictures\Image.jpg" "D:\Users\00002829\Pictures\SFSAPP\VChip_X-Ray\Image04.jpg"
)
IF EXIST "D:\Users\00002829\Pictures\Image.jpg" IF EXIST "D:\Users\00002829\Pictures\SFSAPP\VChip_X-Ray\Image02.jpg" (
    move "D:\Users\00002829\Pictures\Image.jpg" "D:\Users\00002829\Pictures\SFSAPP\VChip_X-Ray\Image03.jpg"
)
IF EXIST "D:\Users\00002829\Pictures\Image.jpg" IF EXIST "D:\Users\00002829\Pictures\SFSAPP\VChip_X-Ray\Image01.jpg" (
    move "D:\Users\00002829\Pictures\Image.jpg" "D:\Users\00002829\Pictures\SFSAPP\VChip_X-Ray\Image02.jpg"
)
IF EXIST "D:\Users\00002829\Pictures\Image.jpg" (
    move "D:\Users\00002829\Pictures\Image.jpg" "D:\Users\00002829\Pictures\SFSAPP\VChip_X-Ray\Image01.jpg"
)
TIMEOUT /t 3
goto start
```

This command only limited to 3 times file rename and move.
Thx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Copy (and increment) Multiple Instances of a File Using Batch File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28697436/how-to-copy-and-increment-multiple-instances-of-a-file-using-batch-file)

Answer (score 0):

Just loop it and find all the files, copy them and rename if exist.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set "source=D:\Users\00002829\Pictures"
set "target=D:\Users\00002829\Pictures\SFSAPP\VChip_X-Ray"

md "%target%"
set /a cnt=0
for /r %%F %target% in (Image.jpg) do if "%%~dpF" neq "%target%\" (
  if exist "%%F" (
  if exist "%target%\%%~nxF" (
    set /a cnt+=1
    set "full=%%F"
    set "name=%%~nF"
    set "ext=%%~xF"
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    copy "!full!" "!target!\!name!!cnt!!ext!" >nul
    endlocal
  ) else copy "%%F" "%target%" >nul
 )
)
```